# WebStorm not detecting React import unless explicitly typed

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

[image]

WebStorm doesn't detect this import from `react`. I always have to explicitly type it.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
```

This is kind of boring when working with many files.

**NOTE**: it does detect & autocomplete imports from current project. But doesn't detect/autocomplete any import from `node_modules` folder mostly.

Comment: Hmm.. screenshot shows that the import is detected - just the import path is wrong. What IDE version do you use? Similar issue ([WEB-49373](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49373)) is fixed in 2021.1

Comment: @lena thanks! i was on some 2020 version. Just updated to the latest version, and now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Webstorm to 2021.1 solved the issue. Thanks [Lena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena) for the comment.